# Is there a way to make a function return true or false if an image is loaded?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I'm working on a small game using the canvas element to draw images onto it and have them act as solid tiles.

In order for the context.drawImage() function to work, the image variable called when drawing is called needs to be loaded into memory first otherwise it will try to draw an undefined image.

Currently i have it set up using the image.onload event like this:

```
var imageloaded = false;
var image = new Image();
var c = document.getElementById("game");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
image.src = "images/image.png";

function drawimage () {
    "use strict";
    if (imageloaded === true) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        ctx.drawimage(image, x, y, width, height);
    }
}

image.onload = function () {
    "use strict";
    imageloaded = true;
    drawimage();
};
```

-Edit- here's a new snippet since i'm doing this for a game where the platforms drawn will move.

```
var drawtimer = setInterval(drawimage, 10);
```

This works but it's a little messy, i need a new global variable for every image i need to load and a onload function to set that variable.

What i'm wondering is, instead of doing:

```
if (imageloaded === true) {
    ctx.drawimage(image, x, y, width, height);
}
```

I could do something that works like:

```
if (image.testloaded() === true) {
    ctx.drawimage(image, x, y, width, height);
}
```

And have that report back if the image is loaded without that having to rely on onload.

For reference i'm working with pure javascript here, i would be willing to use special libraries but an ideal answer would be using pure javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to wait for all images to load and then call drawImage function once, or you want to draw images individually one by one as they load?

Comment: Try placing `image.src = "images/image.png";` after `image.onload = function () {}`

Comment: Here's an [image preloader](https://gist.github.com/m1erickson/1dbeeae071e986ddc45c) that loads all required images before calling a `start` function where all images are fully available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the drawImage() function is only called on load, is it not always loaded and therefore not required to be checked? I.E

```
function drawimage () {
    "use strict";
    if (imageloaded === true) {
        ctx.drawimage(image, x, y, width, height);
    }
}

image.onload = function () {
    "use strict";
    imageloaded = true;
    drawimage();
};
```

is the same as

```
function drawimage () {
    "use strict";
    ctx.drawimage(image, x, y, width, height);
}

image.onload = function () {
    "use strict";
    drawimage();
};
```

Comment: Only issue is since i'm doing this for a game, i need to redraw the image at every tick rather than just once, sorry if the example wasn't very clear on that!

Comment: Perhaps have some sort of object/service which has a function to accept new images when they arrive? So like, in the `onload`, call `ticker.addImage(image);`, I suppose it depends what kind of extra information you want to supply with the image

Comment: Images just need their variable name and their src, adding them to a central variable might work. That way i just need new onloads for each image. I'll see what i can do and post my results.

Comment: @JosephYoung See lowercase `i` at `drawimage`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here: `ctx.drawimage(image, x, y, width, height);` where `i` at `drawimage` should be uppercase `I`: `ctx.drawImage`, see [CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

Also, try moving `image.src = "/path/to/image/";` after `image.onload = function() {}` event declaration

```js
var imageloaded = false;
var image = new Image();
var c = document.getElementById("game");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function drawimage () {
    "use strict";
  console.log(imageloaded)
    if (imageloaded === true) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    }
}

image.onload = function () {
    "use strict";
    imageloaded = true;
    drawimage();
};

image.src = "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature";
```

```html
<canvas id="game" width="50px" height="50px"></canvas>
```

Comment: @Iblob `.drawimage` should be `.drawImage`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't paste this directly from my code luckily for the sake of clarity in the variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everybody! I considered Joseph Young's comment about using a central function or variable to tell what images are loaded and came up with this:

```
var imagesloaded = 0;

image.onload = function () {
    imagesloaded += 1;
}

function imagetestloaded () {
    if(imagesloaded === 1){
        return(true);
    } else {
        return(false);
    }
}

if (imagetestloaded() === true) {
    ctx.drawimage(image, x, y, width, height);
}
```

And this will run if all the images the code expects to see are there.

Comment: @lblob `.drawimage` should be `.drawImage` with uppercase `I`